# Parsing Natural Language

Tags: c++, string, artificial-intelligence

What's the most efficient way to parse natural language?

Let "strings" be a `map<string, void (*func)(int,char**)>` containing strings such as:

```
Set the alarm for *.
Call *.
Get me an * at * for *.
```

and their corresponding functions. Now suppose "input" is a `string` containing a sentence like:

```
Call David.
```

How to implement a function such as `parse` which would take the "input" and match it to one of the strings in the map. Then call its corresponding function, passing it argc and argv containing all the wild card entires (* in strings). What's the most efficient way to implement such a function?

Comment: If you have a predefined list of commands with fixed placeholders that is not really a natural language, but more like a domain specific language or at most a formal language (google DSL - domain specific language). So you could just define a set of regular expressions to match the commands and extract the placeholders for example. But your question is pretty broad to answer it that easily.

Comment: Style comment: Since C++11 we'd write that as `std::function<void(std::vector<std::string>>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this question got a downvote. It's well-posed an non-trivial.

There are plenty of academic approaches to parsing, which are mostly needed for degenerate grammars. "natural language" is perhaps not a well-defined term, and natural languages do have some ambiguity, but such constrained subsets are not problematic.

In this specific example, we see that the different production rules (map entries) are not mutually ambiguous. In fact, the first token is sufficient for disambiguation. And since a `std::map` is sorted, we can do an efficient O(log N) search for that token.

Hence, we only need to derive the substitutions. Again, we'll ignore the degenerate cases. Nobody is going to bother with `"Get me an at at at for at`."`, even though it parses unambiguously.

Instead, for substitutions you simply collect tokens until you get the expected next token. `Get me an * at * for *.` means that the first `*` gets all tokens up to `at`, the second `*` collects tokens up to `for`, and the final `*` gets all remaining tokens.

You see that no backtracking is needed. If parsing fails, there simply is no match.